# ggforce geom_circle jagged and ugly looking

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I'm trying to use ggforce to create a Venn - like plot overlay, but the circles are coming out looking pretty horrible. Is it possible to improve their smoothness? I have tried increasing n (number of points) but that doesnt seem to make any difference.

```
jdCoords %>% ggplot(aes(x,y, label=word)) +
       coord_fixed() + 
       geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0.5, r = 1.25), n=180, linetype="solid", size=1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
       geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0.75, y0 = -1, r = 1.25), n=180, linetype="dotted",size=1,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
       geom_circle(aes(x0 = -0.75, y0 = -1, r = 1.25), n=180, linetype="dashed",size=1,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
       theme_bw() + 
       theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
         axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This probably has more to do with the way you're rendering/exporting the graph. Can you give more information about your platform/output channel? (e.g. are you saving as PNG, PDF, ... ?  Are you including the result in a Word document?)  Below, I use `ggsave("circles.png", dpi=600)` to get a higher-than-usual-resolution PNG.

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
coord_fixed() + 
       geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0.5, r = 1.25), n=180, linetype="solid", size=1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
       geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0.75, y0 = -1, r = 1.25), n=180, linetype="dotted",size=1,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
       geom_circle(aes(x0 = -0.75, y0 = -1, r = 1.25), n=180, linetype="dashed",size=1,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
       theme_bw() + 
       theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
         axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
ggsave("circles.png",dpi=600)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, it does look better with the ggsave export at high DPI. I am using RStudio 1.1 and R 3.6.1 on Manjaro Linux (Gnome). On screen it looks bad, even with the plot zoom. The standard ggplot features look OK though, so must be something to do with the way ggforce is using the graphics?